# how to open a modal dialog by rel attribute

Tags: jquery

I am a newbie in jscript and jquery. I am creating a website, which needs to open modal dialog on clicking on hyper links.

In a sample code (from a website) I saw that, it is using something like this:

```
<a id="SendToFriend" class="button send" href="#modalTellAFriend" rel="modal" data-closetext="Close">

content=jQuery(div#modalTellAFriend)closetext="Fermer"
<span>Send</span>
</a>
```

So, basically, I can add the the  like this:

```
<div id="first modal">
</div>

<div id="second modal">
</div>
```

Now, the simple qn, how do I write the jQuery function for achieving this? I would like to use validate and form for the modal screen as well

Comment: google "jquery lightbox" and see there documentation on how to do this.

Comment: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Comment: Many suggestions for using already made modal dialogues, the reason for that is that it would be simpler to use what is already there than re-inventing the wheel. p.s. I'll recommend [twitter bootstrap model](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) although it has little support for older browsers. [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/sfWBT/1/)

Comment: Thanks colorbox looks the way to go. Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jQuery UI library to create modal dialogs http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

opening different dialogs for different rel attributes could be done like this:

```
$('a[rel="modal_1"]').click(function(){
  $( "#first_modal" ).dialog({
    closeText : 'Fermer',
    modal: true
  });
});

$('a[rel="modal_2"]').click(function(){
  $( "#second_modal" ).dialog({
    closeText : 'Fermer',
    modal: true
  });
});
```